# Knockout Template Binding Not Updating UI

Tags: javascript, templates, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have recursive template that is bound to my model. The problem is that I am modifying the object one at a time so if I click on the next one and I try to load the new object the template doesn't update.

My Template:

```
  <div class="portlet-body" id="details-container" data-bind="template: { name: 'packageTemplate', data: viewModel.packageElements() }"></div>
```

MyModel:

```
var viewModel;
function packageElementViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.packageElements = ko.observable({ Description: ko.observable(), Children:        ko.observableArray() });
}
```

My Initialization:

```
$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': 'http://www.someurl.com/',
    'data': { PackageId: 1},
    'success': function (data) {
        viewModel.packageElements = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

When I select a new package I call this code and I update the variable but the UI doesn't update.:

```
        var id = PackageSummary.packageTable.fnGetData($(this).get(0))['Id'];
        $.ajax({
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': 'http://www.someurl.com',
            'data': { PackageId: id },
            'success': function (data) {
                viewModel.packageElements = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
            },
            'error': function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
```

This is my data:

```
    {
        "Description":"Top",
        "Children":[
            {
                "Description":"Second-Level 1",
                "Children":[
                    {
                        "Description":"Third Level 1",
                        "Children":[]
                    },
                    {
                        "Description":"Third Level 2",
                        "Children":[]
                    },          
                    {
                        "Description":"Third Level 3",
                        "Children":[]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Description":"Second Level 2":[
                    {
                        "Description":"Third Level 1",
                        "Children":[]
                    },
                    {
                        "Description":"Third Level 2",
                        "Children":[]
                    },
                    {
                        "Description":"Third Level 3",
                        "Children":[]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are resetting the `packageElements` in you success method on the ajax call

```
'success': function (data) {
     viewModel.packageElements = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
}
```

that is breaking the bindings with the elements that are set up when you call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)`

Instead what you want to do is just set the `Description` and `Children` properties on the observables that are already in the viewModel

```
'success': function (data) {
    viewModel.packageElements().Description(data.Description);
    viewModel.packageElements().Children(data.Children);
}
```

I made an example doing basically this same thing but with different data.
http://jsfiddle.net/vGuHU/

Also, as a side note. From the code you posted there is no real reason for `packageElements` to be a `ko.observable()`

Comment: Thanks worked liked a charm. I don't know why I made such a stupid mistake.